# Can i connect 3 lists together

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation

I have 3 lists A B C. I want it all of their result shown on one new lists. Could this be done. Will the connection web part be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you use SharePoint Online classic view, you can use SharePoint Designer to create a Linked data source that combine multiple lists.

Reference:[How to Link Two Lists and Create a Combined View](https://www.ignatiuz.com/blog/sharepoint-2013/how-to-link-two-lists-and-create-a-combined-view-in-sharepoint-2013/)